# TYPO3 TCA text linebreaks

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-8.7.x

I need a multi line textarea which gets encapsulated in Fluid by a `<h1>`.

If I make the field in TCA richtext, CKeditor throws a `<p>` tag arround it, so I get

```
<h1><p>bla<br/>next line</p></h1>
```

This is not valid HTML.
I tried some settings in *CKEditor* like `config.autoParagraph: false` but it does not help.

When I make the text field not richttext the frontend does not give linebreaks, however I notice multiline gets saved to the database. Is there a typoscript way of outputting this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may use `<f:format.nl2br>` without RTE.
or `<f:format.raw>`/`<f:format.html>` with RTE.